# How to set a node is selected in treeview when display it in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem with treeview is when in bind data into treeview .I want to set a child node is selected node.For instance:
My treeview:

```
   <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ImageSet="Arrows" NodeWrap="true">           
         <Nodes>
            <asp:TreeNode Value="Child1" Expanded="True" Text="1">
              <asp:TreeNode Value="Grandchild1" Text="A" />
              <asp:TreeNode Value="Grandchild2" Text="B" />
            </asp:TreeNode>
            <asp:TreeNode Value="Child2" Text="2" />
            <asp:TreeNode Value="Child3" Expanded="True" Text="3">
              <asp:TreeNode Value="Grandchild1" Text="A" />
            </asp:TreeNode>
          </Nodes>

    </asp:TreeView>
```

And when page load or i click some button on page . I want to set a "" is the selected node (Selected node will change style or something).

I hope someone help me !Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly then you can use OnSelectedNodeChanged event of tree view.

```
  // Aspx Code
    <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ImageSet="Arrows" NodeWrap="true" OnSelectedNodeChanged="Select_Change"  >           
     <Nodes>
        <asp:TreeNode Value="Child1" Expanded="True" Text="1">
          <asp:TreeNode Value="Grandchild1" Text="A" />
          <asp:TreeNode Value="Grandchild2" Text="B" />
        </asp:TreeNode>
        <asp:TreeNode Value="Child2" Text="2" />
        <asp:TreeNode Value="Child3" Expanded="True" Text="3">
          <asp:TreeNode Value="Grandchild1" Text="A" />
        </asp:TreeNode>
      </Nodes>

</asp:TreeView>
// Message is a label in your aspx
// Code Behind
void Select_Change(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Message.Text = "You selected: " + TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text;

}
```

for more detail visit msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.selectednode.aspx